# Is asking questions on Stack Overflow considered open-source?

Tags: discussion, licensing

Is asking questions on Stack Overflow considered as an open source contribution?

I am asking because I know that some companies explicitly prohibit contribution to open source.  Personally, we have learned a great deal by asking questions here. If majority here say that it is not open source then my friend will check in his company.

Note: The many *apparent duplicates* ask a different question - they ask if Stack Overflow is open source, meaning if the code base of Stack Overflow is open source. I am asking if *asking questions on Stack Overflow* is open source.

Comment: No, that will draw funny looks.  Everybody assumes that the term refers to software and "source" means source code.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Share-alike

Comment: @HansPassant, yeah, I agree.  Just wanted to confirm.  So asking questions here is not open-source, right?

Comment: Random question: Which companies are those, and why would they have such a weird restriction?

Comment: Anyway, if you don't use your real name in your [so] account, it doesn't matter.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom of the page and read what it states there. All content published on SE is cc by-sa 3.0 licensed

Comment: @user202729 Perhaps they are still affected by Microsoft's *"[open source is un-American](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3121792/open-source-tools/whos-no-1-in-open-source-microsoft.html)"* statement (that was before [the](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3144063/open-source-tools/open-source-has-won-and-microsoft-has-surrendered.html) [new Microsoft](https://www.zdnet.com/article/why-microsoft-is-turning-into-an-open-source-company/)).

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly, but it's not wholly dissimilar either.

From what I understand, the typical reasons in the US to forbid open source contributing include:

- potential problems with trade secrets (the company's or its competitors)
- confusion about copyright ownership (as a company typically claims copyright for work-for-hire, including just about all employee code and a large fraction of contractors' as well, whether on or off the clock)
- avoiding employee distraction
- simply not wanting to subsidize a project that will not make the company more money
- residual FUD about the vague hazards of copyleft, libre, and open source licenses

Most of those apply to some degree to SO, though usually less dramatically so. In particular:

- nobody should be posting any sensitive internals here, as those aren't usually all that helpful for answering the question anyway: replace with an MCVE written for the question
- employees can be distracted by answering random SO questions or performing random SO moderation, but they can also save a lot of time *asking* questions
- SO is usually a strong asset for software companies, not an unrelated project
- questions and answers on SO **are** under a copyleft license (but, in the US, are also frequently covered by fair use principles, although admittedly those are frequently quite hairy)

All that to say, depending on a company's situation and the paranoia of its legal department, SO might or might not be forbidden for similar reasons as open-source coding. You really will have to ask.